# Virtualbox out of space

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, lvm

I am getting out of space warnings when I try run and apt-get upgrade.
I am running ubuntu server 14.04 in a virtual machine (virtual box) with a virtual hard drive of 10GB.

It is a very small machine only running bind9 on my local network so strange that it has already run out of space.

If I list the disk space it shows plenty of free space:

```
df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntudns--vg-root  8.5G  4.0G  4.2G  49% /
none                            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                            2.3G  4.0K  2.3G   1% /dev
tmpfs                           462M  456K  461M   1% /run
none                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                            2.3G     0  2.3G   0% /run/shm
none                            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                       236M  236M     0 100% /boot
```

My system uses LVM, which to be honest I don't 100% understand.
This info may help:

```
sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               ubuntudns-vg
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  3
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                2
Open LV               2
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               9.76 GiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              2498
Alloc PE / Size       2498 / 9.76 GiB
Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
VG UUID               aax4CX-stxG-jcxV-s2fB-RQxf-43xe-u7Su89


sudo lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/ubuntudns-vg/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                ubuntudns-vg
LV UUID                J5OD7h-CdmU-BQ4X-FOIv-0dqu-coeI-y8yvKq
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ubuntudns, 2015-09-17 18:20:27 +0200
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                8.76 GiB
Current LE             2242
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/ubuntudns-vg/swap_1
LV Name                swap_1
VG Name                ubuntudns-vg
LV UUID                ed2Wcu-u94R-RGYO-pNx7-Dqjt-3dgO-skT9AP
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ubuntudns, 2015-09-17 18:20:27 +0200
LV Status              available
# open                 2
LV Size                1.00 GiB
Current LE             256
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:1
```

I have read a number of posts trying to figure this out but really not winning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot --- check for example my answer there to get space in a very safe way way  (anyway, you have a very small /boot partition there).

Answer (score 3):

Your `/boot` is full, look

```
/dev/sda1  236M  236M     0 100% /boot
```

That is tiny, you might want to expand this later, but to clear some space now, you can run

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

This should remove any old kernels and any useless packages (thanks @dan in comments for suggesting `autoremove`)
on use

You could also build a `purge` command for this, but I don't know what kernels you have, so some thing like

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.32-22-generic
```

Replacing `linux-image-2.6.32-22-generic` with the kernel to remove, see all installed kernels with

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

or you can open `nautilus` as root

```
gksu nautilus
```

Browse to `/boot` and remove any old kernels in here, DO NOT remove the one you are using, to find the current kernel you are using run

```
uname -a
```

Comment: Is it safe to just delete the files there? Usually when running `apt-get autoremove` to remove old kernels, `apt` does quite some stuff in order to remove them. There are even more configurations that used to happen during the uninstall, when I had the proprietary nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: Should be fine for old kernels but `autoremove` is a solid point, mind if I add that in?

Comment: Of course, go ahead

Comment: @Dan I gave you some upvotes for this info, just in case you wondered where they suddenly came from :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I will clean out the /boot partition and expand it to something more sensible :)

Answer (score 3):

The important part is the `/boot` partition. As you can see, it's completely full:

```
/dev/sda1                       236M  236M     0 100% /boot
```

To free up space from `/boot` folder please delete older kernels that are still installed.

To find out about the kernels installed in your system, use the command:

```
cd /boot && ls | grep generic
```

**OR**

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '/ii/ {print $2}'
```

And to find your current active kernel version, type:

```
uname -r
```

After you have found out about your active and older kernel versions, you can remove the older ones by typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-yourolderkernelversion* && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-3.19.0-32* && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean
```

After everything's done please reboot your system.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to clean apt's cache of previously downloaded files. Run

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

from command line.
After that, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

again.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch `sudo apt-get upgrade` new kernel images and headers shall be downloaded and installed but your `/boot` partition is full:

```
/dev/sda1                       236M  236M     0 100% /boot
```

You need to remove your old kernel images and headers to free it up but `sudo apt-get autoremove` might not work in this case.

This command is to show all kernels and headers that can be removed, excluding the current running kernel:

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')"
```

You can safely remove them all by the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

Finally, you may need to reboot your system.